# Creating missed records - Hive/PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I've this situation of identifying previously available records and duplicate them whenever the corresponding month's record is not available.
Here is the table structure:

metrics table:

| Metric_id | Frequency | Metrics_results |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 293 | Monthly | 151 |
| 293 | Monthly | 152 |
| 293 | Monthly | 153 |
| 294 | quarterly | 173 |
| 294 | quarterly | 174 |
| 295 | Annually | 195 |

Metrics_results table:

| Metrics_results | Month | year | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 151 | Jan | 2020 | 98 |
| 152 | Feb | 2020 | 98 |
| 153 | Mar | 2020 | 99 |
| 173 | Dec | 2019 | 87 |
| 174 | Mar | 2020 | 86 |
| 195 | Jan | 2020 | 90 |

Join metrics and metrics_results table on Metrics_results column for every month and average the value per month.

Expected results:

| Metric_id | Metrics_results | Month | year | value | Flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 293 | 151 | Jan | 2020 | 98 | Existing |
| 293 | 152 | Feb | 2020 | 98 | Existing |
| 293 | 153 | Mar | 2020 | 99 | Existing |
| 294 | 173 | Dec | 2019 | 87 | Existing |
| 294 | 173 | Jan | 2020 | 87 | Copied |
| 294 | 173 | Feb | 2020 | 87 | Copied |
| 294 | 174 | Mar | 2020 | 86 | Existing |
| 295 | 195 | Jan | 2020 | 90 | Existing |
| 295 | 195 | Feb | 2020 | 90 | Copied |
| 295 | 195 | Mar | 2020 | 90 | Copied |

For the metrics which are evaluated monthly, there will be a corresponding record in the metrics_results table. For the ones which are evaluated quarterly(Mar, Jun, Sep, Dec) and annually(Jan), there will be only selected months records available in metrics_results. For such records, have to copy over the previous available month's record if the current month value is not available in averaging.

Eg:

For `Metric id = 294`, there is no record for Jan 2020 & Feb 2020. In this case for Jan 2020 & Feb 2020, have to copy the record of Dec 2019 and change the month to Jan 2020 & Feb 2020 as that's the last value available.

For `metric id = 295`, there is no record for any other month other than Jan 2020. This Jan 2020 record must be copied and replace the month for the rest of the year.

I'm looking for a solution either in `hive query` or in `PySpark`. Any ideas or suggestions will be appreciated.